Non-discrete Homometric Sets
I recently came across this older MathOverflow post: Homometric ⇒
isometric ?. In this post, the author informally proposes a definition of homometry for Riemannian manifolds.
I’m somewhat familiar with the literature on homometry in the context of finite Euclidean point sets, but this post has piqued my interest in possible generalizations of this concept to non-discrete sets. I've tried to search for references on this topic but haven’t found anything directly addressing it.
Are you aware of any existing work that explores this kind of generalization? Alternatively, is there a related or analogous concept in the literature that might go by a different name?
To provide more context, what i called homometry, for a finite sets $X=\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ are the maps that preserved the difference multi-set $\{x_{i}-x_{j}, 1\leq i,j\leq n\}$ or in the case of weak homometry the Euclidean distance multi-set $\{||x_{i}-x_{j}||, 1\leq i,j\leq n\}$.
